# ChromeDriver выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java

при инициализации ChromeDriver, мне выдаёт ошибку, заранее спасибо за быстрый ответ :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.chrome.FatalChromeException: 
Cannot create chrome driver
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', 
java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: chrome
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.start(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:319)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startClient(ChromeDriver.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:72)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:27)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:45)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:55)
at test.seofast.main(test.java:14)
```

вот код:

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class seofast {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");}

}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что используете обратный слеш при указании пути в `System.setProperty`?

Comment: @DanielShatz, да, путь указан правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я почему-то не вижу у вас путь до самого драйвера.
Просто написав chromedriver.exe он его не найдет, нужно указать полный путь, таким образом

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\seleniumDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ. Я сделал всё как вы сказали: я поменял написал полный путь. Но ошибка не изменилась. Жду от вас ответа

Comment: Правильно ли указан первый параметр : "webdriver.chrome.driver" ?

Comment: первый параметр правильный, покажите какой вы путь написали, может быть вы написали один обратный слеш?